# Como consultar select com duas datas formatos diferente no VB.NET?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, vb.net

Fala, guys!
Tenho as datas com dois tipos de formatos diferentes no banco de dados, exemplo:

- MM/dd/yyyy
- dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Mas na hora de fazer na consulta no VB.NET, fiz assim e não funciona.

```
    Public Function teste (ByVal dtpInicio As String, ByVal dtpFim As String) As List(Of Teste)
      'Consulta com a data dd/MM
      Dim retorno As New List(Of Teste)
      Try
         Conectar()
         cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM NOME_TABELA WHERE NOME_COLUNA BETWEEN '" & 
    dtpInicio.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") & "' AND '" & dtpFim.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") & "' ORDER BY NOME_COLUNA"
         dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
         While dr.Read
              retorno.Add(New Teste With {
                           .NOME_COLUNA = dr(0)
              })
              End While
      Catch ex As Exception
              MsgBox(ex.Message)
      Finally
              Desconectar()
      End Try

      'Consulta com a data dd/MM
      Dim retorno As New List(Of Teste)
      Try
         Conectar()
         cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM NOME_TABELA WHERE NOME_COLUNA BETWEEN '" & 
    dtpInicio.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "' AND '" & dtpFim.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "' ORDER BY NOME_COLUNA"
         dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
         While dr.Read
              retorno.Add(New Teste With {
                           .NOME_COLUNA = dr(0)
              })
              End While
      Catch ex As Exception
              MsgBox(ex.Message)
      Finally
              Desconectar()
      End Try
      Return retorno
End Function
```

Alguma dica, galera?

Comment: Tente o formato *AnoMêsDia*, assim: `ToString("yyyyMMdd")`

Comment: Geralmente em banco de dados o formato da data é "YYYY-MM-DD", faça um select na sua base e verifique por favor.

Comment: @WellingtonAraujo eu fiz select na minha base e apareceu. Mas o problema não é SQL e sim VB.NET, pois apareceu a mensagem agora assim: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.IFormatProvider'"

Comment: @JoaoTorresMoreira a coluna de Data da sua tabela realmente foi criada como Datetime? Pelo que estou vendo primeiramente você terá que solucionar os dados da coluna Data da sua tabela, ela tem que ter um formato. Ex: "dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00" ou "yyyy/mm/dd 00:00:00". Verifica se o tipo da coluna é Datetime mesmo.

Comment: Pelo que eu vi a coluna da tabela foi criada como Short Text. OBS: Estou acessando o banco de dados pelo ACCESS.

Comment: Então @JoaoTorresMoreira primeiramente você vai ter que corrigir o banco, senão você vai ficar só tampando buraco, da forma que esta a tabela vai aceitar qualquer coisa no campo, entendeu... veja o artigo do link abaixo...
https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/formatar-o-campo-data-e-hora-no-access-47fbbdc1-52fa-416a-b8d5-ba24d881b698

Answer (score -1):

Opa!

Tenta converter para short date
exemplo

```
    'aqui a primeira data que ta como data e hora
    Dim data1 As DateTime
    data1 = FormatDateTime(data1, DateFormat.ShortDate)

    'aqui a segunda data que ta somente como data
    Dim data2 As DateTime
    data2 = FormatDateTime(data2, DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

Depois você substitui la no código dentro dos selects pelo nome das variáveis que, não sei se fui claro